# Property 'query' is missing in type 'Observable<{}[]>' Ionic Firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, observable, angularfire2

So I tried Josh Morony's tutorial on how to handle Firebase in Ionic:
https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-crud-ionic-2-application-with-firebase-angularfire/

What I've done so far:

**app.module.ts**

1. I've imported `AngularFireDatabaseModule` and in `imports`.

`import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';`

`imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule`

---

**career.ts**

2. I import `AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList`, injected `AngularFireDatabase` in `constructor`.

`import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';`

`constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private database: AngularFireDatabase)`

---

3. I also add a var before constructor

`companies: AngularFireList<any>;`

---

4. And finally, I did this inside constructor.

`this.companies = this.database.list('/company').valueChanges();`

---

`this.companies` showed error. The view loads the list, but the problem is there is still an error and I don't know what has happened. This is what it shows when I hover over `this.companies`:
[image]

I really wish any of you can explain to me what is going on and how to solve this error. Really sorry and thank you very much.

Comment: please add code as text not as an image

Comment: Hi Suraj, I've done edited

Answer (score 5):

In AngularFire2, there are two Object types to note.

`this.database.list('/company')` is of type `AngularFireList<any>`
`this.database.list('/company').valueChanges()` gives `Observable<any[]>`.

If you need the reference to both, you can do the following:

```
this.companiesRef:AngularFireList<any>;
this.companies:Observable<any[]>;
//...
//while accessing,
this.companiesRef = this.database.list('/company');
this.companies = this.companiesRef.valueChanges();
```

Reference to the docs [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md)

Comment: You are awesome, it works already, and now no errors.
Thanks a lot Suraj!

Comment: glad to help :)